# Make pagination work

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

Hi I am trying to render Laravel Pagination through Ajax. I am obtaining the data in JSON format.

**Ajax Code**

```
function pinList() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'pinList',
        type:'POST',
        datatype:'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#pincode-table tbody').html(data.tbody);
            $('.dataTables_paginate').html(data.paginate);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getPinCodeList() {
    $pincode = Pincode::whereRaw("pin_delete NOT LIKE 1")->paginate(2);
    $tbody = "";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($pincode->getCollection()->all() as $pinData) {
        $tbody.="<tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$pinData->pin_code."</td>
                    <td>".$pinData->pin_postOffice."</td>
                    <td>".$pinData->pin_district_id."</td>
                    <td>".$pinData->pin_zone_id."</td>
                 </tr>";
                 $i++;
    }
    $paginate = $pincode->links();
    return Response::json(array('tbody' => $tbody,'paginate' => $paginate));
}
```

When I try to assign the pagination->link to variable and pass it in json format.. it is showing me an empty string.. But when I am echoing it. The links are getting displayed.. I realised the the Pagination link are displayed as View. How can i pass the pagination link through a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to render the view before you send it over a JSON response.

```
$paginate = $pincode->links()->render();
```